# How to represent a collection of inequalities on an axis？

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the problem

[image],

find the condition that must be satisfied by x in order that the expression may be positive for all real values of x.

The result is :

[image]

I would like to polt in axis the soultion of the preceding inequality,reaching such an following effect:[image]

here is my MWE：

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7, nodes={
   execute at begin node=$,
   execute at end node=$
 }]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0) node[above] {x};
\foreach \x/\xpar/\xtext in {
    -0.5 / \bullet / -5,
    -0.1 / \bullet / -1,
    0    /  \circ / 1,
    0.2  / \bullet  / \frac{3}{2},
    0.3  / \bullet / 2,
    0.6  / \circ / 4
}   \draw[thick] (\x,0pt) node {\xpar}  node[below=5pt] {\xtext};
\node[circle,blue,fill=white,draw,inner sep=2pt] at  (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can i achive this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two proposals that approach your drawing without reproducing it precisely.

Both have in common to add a variable in the `foreach` loop `\sol` that is equal to `1` if the interval is solution and `-1` otherwise (if you can't easily use a `boolean`).

They both use the `curve to` operation of the `topaths` library (see p 748 of manual 3.0.1a).

The first one defines the exit and entry angles of the curve:

```
to[out=\sol*-60,in=\sol*-120]
```

The second one uses the `controls` option:

```
to [controls=+(-90:1) and +(-90:1)]
```

### First proposal:

[image: first]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={
   execute at begin node=$,
   execute at end node=$
 }]
\draw[->, thick] (-6,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {x};
\clip(-6,-1)rectangle(4.5,1.5);
\foreach \x/\xpar/\xtext/\sol [remember=\x as \lastx (initially -7)] in {
    -5 / \bullet / -5/1,
    -1 / \bullet / -1/-1,
    0    /  \circ / 1/1,
    1.5  / \bullet  / \frac{3}{2}/1,
    2  / \bullet / 2/-1,
    4  / \circ / 4/1,
    7/\circ/7/-1
}  
{\ifnum \sol=1 
    \draw[thick,pattern=north east lines] (\lastx,0)to[out=\sol*-60,in=\sol*-120](\x,0) node {\xpar}  node[below=5pt] {\xtext};
\else 
    \draw[thick] (\lastx,0)to[out=\sol*-60,in=\sol*-120](\x,0) node {\xpar}  node[below=5pt] {\xtext};
\fi
}
\node[circle,blue,fill=white,draw,inner sep=2pt] at  (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Second proposal:

[image: second]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={
   execute at begin node=$,
   execute at end node=$
 }]
\draw[->, thick] (-6,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {x};
\clip(-6,-1)rectangle(4.5,1.5);
\foreach \x/\xpar/\xtext/\sol [remember=\x as \lastx (initially -7)] in {
    -5 / \bullet / -5/1,
    -1 / \bullet / -1/-1,
    0    /  \circ / 1/1,
    1.5  / \bullet  / \frac{3}{2}/1,
    2  / \bullet / 2/-1,
    4  / \circ / 4/1,
    6/\circ/6/-1
}  
{\ifnum \sol=1 
    \draw[thick,pattern=north east lines] (\lastx,0)to [controls=+(-90:1) and +(-90:1)](\x,0) node {\xpar}  node[below=15pt] {\xtext};
\else 
    \draw[thick] (\lastx,0)to [controls=+(90:1) and +(90:1)](\x,0) node {\xpar}  node[below=15pt] {\xtext};
\fi
}
\node[circle,blue,fill=white,draw,inner sep=2pt] at  (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I take that you want a cartoon, not draw the function (which has poles in this domain).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7, nodes={
   execute at begin node=$,
   execute at end node=$
 }]
\draw[->, thick] (-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0) node[above] {x};
\foreach \x/\xpar/\xtext [count=\Z] in {
    -0.5 / \bullet / -5,
    -0.1 / \bullet / -1,
    0    /  \circ / 1,
    0.2  / \bullet  / \frac{3}{2},
    0.3  / \bullet / 2,
    0.6  / \circ / 4
}   \draw[thick] (\x,0pt) coordinate (p-\Z) node {\xpar}  node[below=5pt] {\xtext};
\node[circle,blue,fill=white,draw,inner sep=2pt] at  (0,0) {};
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (-0.8,-0.1) to[out=0,in=-135] (p-1) --(-0.8,0); 
\draw (p-1) to[out=45,in=135] (p-2);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (p-2) to[out=-45,in=-135,looseness=2] (p-3);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (p-3) to[out=-45,in=-135,looseness=1.2] (p-4);
\draw (p-4) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=2] (p-5);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (p-5) to[out=-45,in=-135,looseness=1] (p-6);
\draw (p-6) to[out=45,in=180] ++ (0.2,0.1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is  a little different，not a sine wave rolling up and down

Comment: @mcmxciv Better now?